# Is there any alternative for pandas.DataFrame function for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, kivy, buildozer

I am developing an application for Android with Kivy, and package it with Buildozer. The core of my application is using pandas and specially the DataFrame function. It failed when I tried to package it with Buildozer even if I had put pandas in the requirements. So I want to use another library that can be used with Buildozer. So does anyone know about a great alternative to the pandas.DataFrame function with the numpy library for example or another one ?

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Similar* to Pandas.DataFrame.
As database you likely know **SQLite** (in python see SQLAlchemy and SQLite3).
On the raw tables (i.e., pure matrix-like) **Numpy** (Numpy.ndarray), it lacks of some database functionalities compared to Pandas but it is fast and you could easily implement what you need. You can find many comparisons between Pandas and Numpy.
Finally,depending on your needs, some simple python **dictionaries**, maybe OrderedDict.